# Irreducible polynomial in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose $2k + 1 \equiv 3 \mod 4$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$.

Is the polynomial: $p_k(x) = x^{2k + 1} + x^{2k - 1} \dots + x + 1$ irreducible in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$?

I do not know whether it is true or not...

(*Side note:*
I've had a question in a test that is solved immediately if the statement above turns out to be true (a two parted question that would be solved by proving a single statement). The question was much simpler then trying to prove/disprove the above statement but I missed the easy way (very unfortunately and quite disappointingly after so much preparation and work). I decided to go about it my own way, brute forcing instead of trying to think outside the box.)

The idea I had in mind - the statement is true:

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $p_k$ is reducible and suppose $g, f \in \Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ are such that $gf = p_k$ and $\deg(f), \deg(g) \geq 1$. Also w.l.o.g $\deg f > \deg g$.

Denote $$
f = x^s + b_{s - 1}x^{s - 1} + \dots + b_1 x + 1 \\
g = x^r + a_{r - 1}x^{r - 1} + \dots + a_1 x + 1
$$

Note then, that $r + s = 2k + 1$ so either $r$ is even and $s$ is odd or vice versa. Suppose $r$ is even and $s$ is odd.

We now proceed to equate the coefficients between $fg$ and $p_k$.

Also, $a_1 + b_1 \equiv 1 \mod 2$ because the coefficient of $x$ in $p_k$. Suppose $b_1 \equiv 0 \mod 2 \wedge a_1 \equiv 1 \mod 2$.

Now for the coefficient of $x^2$ we have $a_1b_1 + a_2 + b_2 \equiv a_2 + b_2 \mod 2 \equiv 0 \mod 2$. Yielding yet again two possibilities. Suppose $a_2 \equiv b_2 \mod 2 \equiv 1 \mod 2$.

And in general we can say:
$$
 a_l + b_l + \sum_{i = 1}^{l - 1}a_i b_{l - i} \equiv \cases{1 \mod 2 & l is odd \\
                                                 0 \mod 2 & l is even}
$$
Where $l \in \{1, 2, 3, \dots, r + s - 1\}$. I think maybe I need to prove that all the even powers must reside in $f$ where all the odd powers must reside in $g$ and get a contradiction in some way. But I really don't know what I should do. Maybe induction? But what is the hypothesis?

Thank you for your trouble! And I am sorry if what I've tried above is confusing and unclear. I had no time to think when I tried to solve it and I am kind of stuck now.

Comment: What is the ... in $p_k(x)$?

Comment: Signifies that only the odd powers are present. (Coefficients of even powers are zero except for the free term)
For example we have $p_7(x) = x^7 + x^5 + x^3 + x + 1$

Comment: Your $p_7(x)$ must be $p_3(x)$

Comment: Note that $2k+1\equiv3\pmod4$ is the same as saying that $k$ is odd.

Comment: Interesting question... +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. The first counterexample is
\begin{multline*}
x^{23}+x^{21}+x^{19}+x^{17}+x^{15}+x^{13}+x^{11}+x^9+x^7+x^5+x^3+x+1 \\= \left(x^3+x^2+1\right) \left(x^4+x+1\right)
   \left(x^{16}+x^{15}+x^{12}+x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^4+x^2+1\right).
\end{multline*}
Among the odd values of $k$ up to $200$, there are $15$ irreducible polynomials and $85$ reducible polynomials of this form.

Comment: Apparently the intended exam solution did not go through this statement.

Comment: Yes it turns out I misread--that it was *related* to the exam question, and not an exam question itself...

Comment: Thank you! In the exam my end goal was to show that there are infinitely many irreducible polynomials of this form and I guessed all of them are irreducible (quite wrongly as this answer shows). And although it might be right that there are infinitely many of them, it is probably not too trivial to show. A question to ponder about for another day.

Comment: Nice! I wonder whether an asymptotic density guesstimate of irreducibles is possible :-)

Comment: It's a [standard lemma](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.0409.pdf) that over any finite field, approximately $1/n$ of the polynomials of degree $n$ are irreducible. So if the polynomials $p_k(x)$ for $k$ odd act like random polynomials, the number of irreducible ones for $k\le K$ would be approximately $\log(K/2)$ (hence certainly of density $0$). Computations up to $K=500$ are quite consistent with logarithmic growth.

Comment: There are some algebraic patterns: that $x^3+x^2+1$ divides $p_{11}(x)$ actually implies that $x^3+x^2+1$ divides $p_k(x)$ for all $k\equiv 4\pmod 7$. In general, if some $p_{k_0}(x)$ has an irreducible factor of degree $d$, then that factor will also divide $p_k(x)$ for all $k\equiv k_0\pmod{2^d-1}$ (implied by the fact that all irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ over $\Bbb F_q$ divide $x^q-x$ by "splitting field" generalities). So there are non-random patterns, but if anything they seem like they would decrease the number of irreducibles. Maybe a sieve can prove density $0$ in this way.

Comment: Yeah, your guess is very likely correct. Estimating the fraction of primitive ones (guaranteed to appear as factors) among the irreducibles of a certain degree may require more information about the asymptotics of Euler totient than I know :-)

Comment: Ah well I'm supposed to be really good with asymptotics of multiplicative functions, so hit me up with the details if you want :)

Answer (score 2):

Some simple (non-computer) ways of seeing the existence of non-trivial factors. In the end I prove that every primitive polynomial $\in \Bbb{F}_2[x]$ of degree $>2$ is a factor of infinitely many polynomials of this type.

---

I reindex the polynomials and call $P_\ell(x)$ the polynomial with degree $4\ell-1$. The geometric sum formula tells us that
$$
P_\ell(x)=1+x\frac{1+x^{4\ell}}{1+x^2}.
$$
So an element $\alpha\in K:=\overline{\Bbb{F}_2}$ is a root of $P_\ell(x)$, if $\alpha\neq1$ and
$$
\alpha(1+\alpha^{4\ell})=1+\alpha^2.\qquad(*)
$$
Because $\alpha\notin \Bbb{F}_2$, it is a root of unity of some order $M$. From equation $(*)$ it thus follows that if $\alpha$ is a root of $P_\ell(x)$, it is also a root of $P_k(x)$ for all $k\equiv \ell\pmod M$. In other words $P_\ell(x)$ has a non-trivial common factor with all the polynomials $P_{\ell+j M}(x)$, $j=1,2,3,\ldots$.

For example the polynomial $P_1(x)=x^3+x+1$ is a well-known irreducible. Its roots have order $M=7$, because $7=2^3-1$ is a Mersenne prime. Consequently $P_1(x)$ is a factor of $P_8(x)$, $P_{15}(x)$ etc. Indeed, (firing up Mathematica)
$$
P_8(x)=\left(x^3+x+1\right) \left(x^7+x^6+x^5+x^3+x^2+x+1\right)
   \left(x^{21}+x^{20}+x^{16}+x^{14}+x^{13}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x
   ^4+x+1\right).
$$
Similarly, $P_2(x)=1+x+x^3+x^5+x^7$ is also irreducible (less well known but still doable by paper & pencil). As $2^7-1=127$ is also a Mersenne prime, we can deduce that $P_2(x)\mid P_{129}(x)$.

---

Reverse engineering one of the factors in the example ($\ell=6$) Greg Martin gave as follows.
Let $\gamma$ be a root of the primitive polynomial $1+x+x^4$. So $\gamma$ has order $2^4-1=15$. We have $1+\gamma=\gamma^4$, so $1+\gamma^2=\gamma^8$. The element
$\gamma^5=\gamma+\gamma^2$ is a third root of unity, so $(\gamma^5)^2=\gamma^{10}=1+\gamma+\gamma^2$. So with $\ell=6$ we see that
$$
\gamma^{4\ell}=\gamma^{15+9}=\gamma^9
$$
and consequently
$$
\gamma(1+\gamma^{4\ell})=\gamma+\gamma^{10}=1+\gamma^2.
$$
The equation $(*)$ thus says that $\gamma$ is a root $P_6(x)$, and hence $1+x+x^4\mid P_6(x)$ as well as $P_{21}(x)$, $P_{36}(x)$ etc.

---

Furthermore, rewriting $(*)$ we also see that $\alpha$ is a root of $P_\ell(x)$,
if
$$
\alpha^{4\ell}=\frac{1+\alpha+\alpha^2}\alpha.\qquad(**)
$$
If $\alpha$ is a primitive element of any finite field $F=\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$, $m>2$, then so is $\alpha^4$. The assumption $m>2$ implies that $1+x+x^2$ is not the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, so the right hand side of $(**)$ is a non-zero element of $F$. By primitivity of $\alpha^4$, it is thus equal to $(\alpha^4)^\ell$ for some natural number $\ell$, $0<\ell<2^m-1$.
So  $(**)$ holds for this choice of $\ell$ as well as every other integer in the residue class of $\ell$ modulo $2^m-1$.

**Conclusion:** If $r(x)\in\Bbb{F}_2[x]$ is a primitive polynomial of degree $m>2$, there exists infinitely many integers $\ell$ (a residue class of $2^m-1$) such that
$r(x)\mid P_\ell(x)$.

Comment: I got carried away a bit, sorry. Initially I wanted to simply write down the reasoning leading to the fact that $P_1(x)\mid P_{1+7j}(x)$. Then I wanted to explain the quartic factor in Greg Martin's post, and it just snowballed from there :-)

Comment: The next question would be which non-primitive irreducible polynomials appear as factors of some $P_\ell(x)$? The lowest degree such polynomial is $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$, the fifth cyclotomic polynomial. It is easy to verify that $(**$ never holds, when $\alpha$ is a fifth root of unity. Simply because the r.h.s. is not in $\mu_5$. $2^5-1=31$ is a Mersenne prime, so all the irredusible quintics are primitive. Degree six?